# display result of expression with variable parameters

Tags: vega-lite

I have a couple of parameters bound to sliders, and I'm trying to figure out how to display a calculated field (in this case the current Mean Squared Error), based on these values and the data values. The two subproblems here:

1. The calculation itself. I calculated the regression line using "datum", but I'm wondering if there's something like a summation operator. For mean squared error, I'd want to be able to know both the number of elements in the data, as well as so something like "SUM(Math.pow(datum.y - (datum.x * slope + intercept),2))/LENGTH(datum.x)" or
   `{calculate: "data(error).reduceRight((acc, cur)=> acc + Math.pow(cur, 2), 0)/length(error)", as: "MSE-calc"}`. I don't think I can use `reduceRight` in this expression though, and then I don't think I can refer to that variable as the parameter value either (correct me if I'm wrong!) I did note that there is built-in function for regression lines and an easy way to get r^2 values. This is just a minimal stand-in example for a type of calculation I would like to do that will not have a built-in function, however.
2. The sliders appear in `<form class="vega-bindings" />`. Is there a proper way to group the output of the above calculation in this same html element? The examples I find of display text seem to be on the charts only. My workaround below is to make a text input and flag it as readonly. This works! But maybe there's a "proper" way of doing this.
   Thanks!

[Vega-Lite Editor Example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ADE6AAiRHhsuIpA4k6pAghoA2qFn3L6CILY5LS4kiCDB4AjEpMNLLKaKCROAyYaCB2smR+IAiRaAAMSsgAHmhiShCYcDg5lCEAvtUKru5JkWXqUOWJ-oHBOeGR0aixsvGJ6ClpVpl6-ABMeUiFqLMgpeWVNXUNCB4gALIAygCiVgFB21CBUAyCSGXKRifBRvDq6RFRMSBxCUll+R3JcCQyjkggAnkkXkCQeDagBdJTKG4oAYgB5qZygBa5EDg1D8bKUAAcIQAnNNCYSxNlqWIAOzTEJiAAsGxACzCOLQIUo2TJIQAbEzaQBmYWMpkhEK0wmshZLXHTHm0-mSkKEknC-n87JMsnC2VoYVKXHCyhM7Kkxkawm0kLZOlSg2oJnGtBMyhiMUUkl27Iqpma-lO4qc1ASLX8hliabRsRiMlap3811hyj8n2R20k7IM3Wep20lO0s3S6bC3XKxmkklOwlFs0ZwkW7ViJshGNOkkpklE6ZM9Mk-nx4XZWkkkks2F1ECYFIQABmbHUCAxIHOgku1zKSURmAYCEo+SMACojF4fHAjABqIzNOCtdpWJCOUbkF4QCC6ECs9ebm7bXd90oUEjH4IwAApAIPI9T3PXxr1vWQWjabQAEonxfEB73UJdv3hVEoDkc4RhcEBrlBe9V2QdQAGskhwNhmisOBZEI5RIjID4FlAecaDgQR+jZKxMFBXwkgARwYJAkLoG4aFIb8Ux4viBKScElBEsT0Ek6SdEwOSFNqVlqLo9BzHSFi2I4riPl4-jBMKDTRO2HSZP0nRDKUkA7NU18yHfT85GE5yJKktyDMsIyp3qDJbFM0BNO2cyrAYpjUFnYJp0sth2NSGyUR8hzgq0kBXL0iLFNDZT7KSbDcKckqytkjzIrhaogA)

```json
    {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "description": "Fit a line",
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "slope",
          "value": 1,
          "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 5, "step": 0.1}
        },
        {
          "name": "intercept",
          "value": 0,
          "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -2, "max": 2, "step": 0.1}
        },    
       {
          "name": "MSE",
          "value": "calculated value here",
          "bind": {"input": "text", "readonly": "readonly"}}
      ],
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"x": 0, "y": -0.8192885000572154},
          {"x": 1, "y": 1.0921647331541178},
          {"x": 2, "y": 2.0761118936604923},
          {"x": 3, "y": 3.4019159387105717},
          {"x": 4, "y": 4.531889100614366},
          {"x": 5, "y": 5.666215252559266},
          {"x": 6, "y": 5.691627190214953},
          {"x": 7, "y": 7.47823497615199},
          {"x": 8, "y": 7.491680160580125},
          {"x": 9, "y": 9.824699659307994}
        ]
      },
      "transform": [
        {"calculate": "datum.x * slope + intercept", "as": "regression"},
        {"calculate": "datum.y - (datum.x * slope + intercept)", "as": "error"}
      ],
      "vconcat": [
        {
          "layer": [
            {
              "mark": "point",
              "encoding": {
                "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
                "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
              }
            },
            {
              "mark": "line",
              "encoding": {
                "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
                "y": {"field": "regression", "type": "quantitative"}
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {"field": "error", "type": "quantitative"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**EDIT: Partial Solution**

It doesn't look like there's currently a way to bind a variable to the text input box. The motivation was to have about a half dozen parameters displayed there that are formatted the same way as the sliders without needing to specify matching styling, alignment, or specific *(x, y)* offsets from the parent chart for each parameter.

Without an easy way to specify a more generic reducing function, this example equation had to be broken up into three more steps, 1 `joinaggregate` and 2 `calculate`s. With a half dozen more complicated equations, I'll have to see if this becomes too unreadable without comments. I think the better approach is to rework this with the javascript api so I can access the data directly for this scenario. Thanks!

[Updated Example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ADE6AAiRHhsuIpA4k6pAghoA2qFn3L6CILY5LS4kiCDB4AjEpMNLLKaKCROAyYaCB2smR+IAiRaAAMSsgAHmhiShCYcDg5lCEAvtUKru5JkWXqUOWJ-oHBOeGR0aixsvGJ6ClpVpl6-ABMeUiFqLMgpeWVNdUAukrKSJgoAyABQWrOoAu5IACeaPzZlAAcIQCc0-f3YtmfYgDs0yFiABY6mc0GErqDKNkXiEAGwA74AZgR-wBIRC33uwJACyW10WkO+MLRIXuTwRMJh2QBLwRWIWCKUeIRlAB2We-zJ92+IWyP3RdLQAMZgsoYmRbyePOyRIB5JhAtQxXBisoFJhfzE001YjELwpCphwpVMMl6u5T2yf2pYoV3yN3xZGOmCOphP+zyeCvu9pZpvubMpYn9IS1CqeRqeD2mAJNTxhuoR2W+TyeQI2dRAmBSEAAZmx1AhTiAoIEoAxBLsPCpdgwEJR8kYAFRGLw+OBGADURmacFa7SsSEco3I6jUEF0ICxJcEZYrZSSO0wtcolyM-CMAApF8uG83W75O93ZC02toAJQDocgXvqfOT+rF0vlytJHBsADuW5rdZv+YU0wvJRBySCAAEdf3Ue9QEkNhIiQMgyFHCh51QFwQB8JIEDgJB5CUHMaDgQR+mWcD1FvSCgKvBw4GnKBJ3TB9aOfFCQAAcgAJQAWQAZQAUVQIxWI7PMC12DcwPUTAvyXOtqNos8FEEygERzVjAJAYDRmo+j-CgOQSxGNCK0uXsi2QdQAGtX1g48rDgWQ9OUSIyBibFXPwwjiMKJRMEuXwklAhgcJ0PYdFIe9lVADyiKSa4fL8qtAuCuhdhocLaixcyrPQcx0nsxznNchYooImL0G8zMEoCoLjxSsLLAzPESs8pIkNHCBxzkKxfP89Aktq0K0oa2oGNAYzTNQ0Astcnqq1yqw32aNAs2CDN8rYJzUiK9zSq87qqr6mqQtS9KjWasrrzIu94t6kB+uO+rJ1qB9poOWakjKfIOmLNhvEg9AmArKArKUc4gOEMg9GSGgyCwKw8WjbI1ocjbCreuAvpmg6QFkNhJkCKxouIgsIGGzZyaAA)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Fit a line",
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "slope",
      "value": 1,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 5, "step": 0.1}
    },
    {
      "name": "intercept",
      "value": 0,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": -2, "max": 2, "step": 0.1}
    },
  ],
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0, "y": -0.8192885000572154},
      {"x": 1, "y": 1.0921647331541178},
      {"x": 2, "y": 2.0761118936604923},
      {"x": 3, "y": 3.4019159387105717},
      {"x": 4, "y": 4.531889100614366},
      {"x": 5, "y": 5.666215252559266},
      {"x": 6, "y": 5.691627190214953},
      {"x": 7, "y": 7.47823497615199},
      {"x": 8, "y": 7.491680160580125},
      {"x": 9, "y": 9.824699659307994}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.x * slope + intercept", "as": "regression"},
    {"calculate": "datum.y - (datum.x * slope + intercept)", "as": "error"},
    {"calculate": "pow(datum.error,2)", "as": "sqerror"},
    {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "mean", "field": "sqerror", "as": "msecalc"}]},
    {"calculate": "'RMSE: '+format(sqrt(datum.msecalc), '.3f')", "as":"rmse"}
  ],
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "point",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
            "y": {"field": "regression", "type": "quantitative"}
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {"layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "error", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "color": "black",
        "x": 0,
        "align": "right",
        "y": 240
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"type": "nominal", "field": "rmse"}
      }
      }]}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a join aggregate transform which you can use in downstream calculations.
2. Why do you need to group the output in the same element? FYI, you can just display a text mark with the output of your calculation and position it below the chart.
   Also, have you seen the following example (although is is Vega rather than VL) which may be useful: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega/pi-monte-carlo